# Timeline change slide/date with arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timeline

I am working on an horizontal slider ([this one](https://codyhouse.co/gem/horizontal-timeline/)) and I am trying to add a new functionality: if the arrows are clicked, they will go to the next/prev date, instead of scrolling the time line.

At the moment, it just shows the next/prev date when the date itself is clicked, but I want to do that too when the arrows are clicked.

This is the code for the right arrow, This is how the click on the date works (I want to add the same functionality for the arrows) and HTML:

```js
//detect click on the next arrow
timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].on('click', '.next', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //updateSlide(timelineComponents, timelineTotWidth, 'next'); //Disabled this functionality

});



//detect click on the a single event - show new event content
timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].on('click', 'a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  updateOlderEvents($(this));
  updateFilling($(this), timelineComponents['fillingLine'], timelineTotWidth);
  updateVisibleContent($(this), timelineComponents['eventsContent']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="cd-horizontal-timeline">
  <div class="timeline">
    <div class="events-wrapper">
      <div class="events">
        <ol>
          <li><a href="#0" data-date="16/01/2014" class="selected">16 Jan</a></li>
          <li><a href="#0" data-date="28/02/2014">28 Feb</a></li>
          <li><a href="#0" data-date="20/04/2014">20 Mar</a></li>
        </ol>

        <span class="filling-line" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </div>
      <!-- .events -->
    </div>
    <!-- .events-wrapper -->

    <ul class="cd-timeline-navigation">
      <li><a href="#0" class="prev inactive">Prev</a></li>
      <li><a href="#0" class="next">Next</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- .cd-timeline-navigation -->
  </div>
  <!-- .timeline -->

  <div class="events-content">
    <ol>
      <li data-date="28/02/2014">
        <h2>Event title here</h2>
        <em>February 28th, 2014</em>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium officia, fugit recusandae ipsa, quia velit nulla adipisci? Consequuntur aspernatur at, eaque hic repellendus sit dicta consequatur quae, ut harum ipsam molestias maxime non nisi
          reiciendis eligendi! Doloremque quia pariatur harum ea amet quibusdam quisquam, quae, temporibus dolores porro doloribus.
        </p>
      </li>

      <li data-date="20/04/2014">
        <h2>Event title here</h2>
        <em>March 20th, 2014</em>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium officia, fugit recusandae ipsa, quia velit nulla adipisci? Consequuntur aspernatur at, eaque hic repellendus sit dicta consequatur quae, ut harum ipsam molestias maxime non nisi
          reiciendis eligendi! Doloremque quia pariatur harum ea amet quibusdam quisquam, quae, temporibus dolores porro doloribus.
        </p>
      </li>

      <li data-date="20/05/2014">
        <h2>Event title here</h2>
        <em>May 20th, 2014</em>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum praesentium officia, fugit recusandae ipsa, quia velit nulla adipisci? Consequuntur aspernatur at, eaque hic repellendus sit dicta consequatur quae, ut harum ipsam molestias maxime non nisi
          reiciendis eligendi! Doloremque quia pariatur harum ea amet quibusdam quisquam, quae, temporibus dolores porro doloribus.
        </p>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</section>
```

**EDITED:**
How far I got on the arrow right functionality:

```
//detect click on the next arrow
timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].on('click', '.next', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].find('.selected').next('li').addClass('selected'); //This is not working

});
```

[image]

To add the class to the next li, I am doing this, but it doesn't work:

```
timelineComponents['timelineEvents'].find('.selected').next('li').addClass('selected');
```

Comment: Maybe triggering the click event manually `timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].find('a.selected').click()` can work...

Comment: @BalázsVarga but it has to do it on the arrow: timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].on('click', '.next', function(event) and on click, slide to the next/prev date...

Comment: I mean, when you click on the next button, you can trigger the click event of the bulltes. To trigger clicking on the next date, you should do something like this: `timelineComponents['timelineNavigation'].on('click', '.next', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); timelineComponents['eventsWrapper'].find('a.selected').parents('li').next('li').find('a').click(); });`

Comment: Your edit doesn't work because there's no `li` element after the `.selected` element (`.selected` is an `a` inside a `li`). You have to go up one level by the `.parents('li')` and find the `next('li')`, then inside it, the `a`.

Comment: I've modified a bit your code and it's adding the class all right. But there're 2 element that must have the class selected. I've added a image to the post, so you can see the other element

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your one line of code, so I think there's an ordering issue. I can't tell it from what you've posted.